# Windows Phone 7.5 touchend event is not fired

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I write application using Cordova 2.2.0 framework for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.
I have the following code which works on both: Android and iOS but does not on Windows Phone 7.5.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", devReady, false);
    devReady();
});

function devReady()
{                       
    document.getElementById('index_login_butt').addEventListener('touchend',     indexLoginClicked, false);
}


function indexLoginClicked() 
{       
        //console.log("######## indexLogin");
        var color = $(this).css("background-color");
        var lighter = lighterColor(color, .1);
        $(this).css("background-color", lighter);
}
```

I spend already whole day to find out why this code does not work. I don't know in which/how should I initialize these blocks to make them work. I tried to look in the internet but couldn't find anything usefull.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.x has Internet Explorer 9 Mobile which doesn't implement touch APIs. You have to resort to use "click" event instead.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Now I can see that I should use mousedown event instead. Thank you again.